# How to copy a rubygem from one installation to another one

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel

What must I do when I want to copy an installed gem from one installation to another one without using the `gem` command?

I have to install SQLite3 on a server without an internet connection. Normally I can do it with a copy of the gem-file:

```
gem install --local sqlite3-1.4.0.gem --platform ruby
```

But for SQLite3 it needs a connection to the internet to get libraries to compile some binaries. The installation worked well on a computer with an internet connection.

So my idea was to take my successful installation on the same OS and same Ruby version and copy all the related components, but this did not work.

When I called:

```
require 'sequel'
db = Sequel.sqlite
```

I got this error:

```
LoadError: The specified module could not be found
d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so 
(Sequel::AdapterNotFound)
```

In the trace is:

```
d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': LoadError: 126: The specified module could not be found.   - d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.1/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `require'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `rescue in require'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.17.0/lib/sequel/adapters/sqlite.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.17.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:88:in `load_adapter'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.17.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:17:in `adapter_class'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.17.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:45:in `connect'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:121:in `connect'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:399:in `adapter_method'
  from d:/bin/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sequel-5.17.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:406:in `block (2 levels) in def_adapter_method'
  from _ruby_version.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

but the file exists:

[image: File structure]

What is my error?

I'm using Windows Server 2016.

I found a [precompiled version of SQLite3](https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/9tfvju3tbxvdm0y4/artifacts/sqlite3-1.4.0.20190219-x64-mingw32.gem) in a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/240) which works for me, but I would like to use a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bundler](https://bundler.io/) for this.

In short:

- Run `gem install bundler` on each machine you're using.
- Maintain a project `Gemfile` listing all requirements
- Run `bundle install` when your Gemfile changes and `bundle update` to update to latest versions. This will generate the Gemfile.lock file.
- Prefix ruby execution with `bundle exec`, e.g. `bundle exec ruby myscript` or `bundle exec rails c`

That's a brief summary, but please read up more on Bundler. It's an essential part of modern Ruby deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `package` option of bundler.

First you need to cache your dependencies into `vendor/cache` with:

```
bundle package --all --all-platforms
```

This will install all the dependencies of your Gemfile locally, then add the directory to your source code repository.

When deploying make sure you use `bundle install --local` to use the local version.

See the [documentation](https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-package.1.html) for `bundle package` for more information.

Comment: I tried to do the steps you wrote and I got the message `Bundle complete!`. But my errors is still the same. Does "bundle" include all sources, to compile the native parts of the installation?